# Не появляется виджет в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('Canvas')
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
reg=root.register(callback)

# другие виджеты

panelize = tk.LabelFrame(root, text='Панелизация')
panelize.pack(side='top', fill='y', anchor='w')
```

Я сначала подумал что уже существующие виджеты перекрывают новый но даже когда я удалил существующие новый не появился. Так же я проверил нету ли у меня фрейма который перекрывает всё окно и новый виджет

Comment: А пробовали в этот фрейм что-то добавлять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы внутрь него ничего "не положили" (например `tk.Label(panelize, text='Some text').pack()` ), то эта рамка и не будет видна.
Ибо, как минимум, её ширина равна 0.
Можно ещё заранее задать ей ширину и высоту.
Или заставить её занять всё пространство
`panelize.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True, anchor='w')`.